# Informing Stack Overflow users from Poland about a conference

Tags: discussion

In October we are planning a nation-wide conference on R in Poland. I see a growing society of R users on Stack Overflow, some of them seem to be from Poland.

Is there a way to post something on Stack Overflow to inform R users about this conference?

Comment: Sounds like a thing to pin in the appropriate chat room

Comment: or maybe make it a community ad: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7438/community-promotion-ads-2014

Comment: Thank you for this hits!

Comment: @Jan Unfortunately the guidelines in place on Stack Overflow wouldn't allow an ad like that.

Comment: @animuson why not?

Comment: @JanDvorak You linked to SU, apparently [the one on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210389/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) is for open source projects only.

Comment: You could ask the team whether they'd be willing/able to run an ad aimed at Polish users in the R tag, but don't be too disappointed if it's not possible (it's likely not)

Comment: I doubt that such ads are going to be accepted; it's a slippery slope from there on out.